# How can I animate the pinning button on / off (cloth)?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I do not find the way to insert a keyframe on the pinning button (cloth).
It would still be better to have an animate pinning weight.

Comment: Could you post some reference image? What you have so far?

Comment: C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\Pinning.jpg

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

I just found this solution.
I would like to see if there are other ways to control vertex group in the simulation cloth.
My problem was to attack and detach a group of vertices. Turn off Pinning in cloth simulation.

Comment: You can use [dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#weight) to alter vertex group weights.