# How do I remove a cloth pinning at some point of the animation?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, physics, keyframes, vertex-groups

I'm quite new in the blender world.
I'm animating a balloon that has three fix points when it inflates/deflates and I want it to fly away at a certain point of the animation following the physics I already added, like the wind. I've seen that i can move the points and insert keyframes in edit mode but I want it to be realistic and just fly away.
**Is there a way to remove or deselect a vertex group at some point?**

[image: Beginning]

[image: Object]

[image: Edit]

Comment: hello, could you please show some illustrations or picture of what you want to do?

Comment: yes of course, tell me if you need something more to understand

Comment: do you mean this vertex group is used to pin the mesh during cloth simulation? then you don't want it to be taken account of?

Comment: yes exactly is what i'm trying to do

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks impossible to directly animate the *Cloth Pinning*. The question has been asked [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/animating-the-pinning-of-a-cloth-object/517151) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88807/how-can-i-animate-the-pinning-button-on-off-cloth), but I'm not sure to understand everyhting.

I've found an other solution, a rather simple one, with the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier, but there must be others:

- Create your object, give it 2 vertex groups, one for the pinning, the second one must be empty. Give it the *Cloth* physics.

[image]

- Create a *Force Field > Force* next to your object. Animate it: give it *Strength* of 0 until frame 49 for example, keyframe it at frame 49, at frame 50 give it a *Strength* of 30.

[image]

- Give your object a *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier, put it above the *Cloth* in the modifiers stack. Choose *Vertex Group A* > the pinning group, *Vertex Group B* > the empty group, *Mix Set > VGroup A or B*. Keyframe the *Default Weight A* and *Default Weight B* values: A will be 0 from frame 1 to 49, then 1 at frame 50, B will be 1 from frame 1 to 49, then 0 at frame 50.

[image]

- It seems to work as planned, from frame 1 to 49, the object collapse with the pinning hanging it, at frame 50 it is blown away by the force field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Vertex Weight Edit* above *Cloth*

Choose your vertex group and put weight in `0.999`, then you have an option called *Group Remove*.

Answer (score 0):

The Vertex Weight Edit answer above is mostly correct, but partly incomplete. If you're pinning vertices because they're attached to an armature that is applying dynamic forces to the rest of the mesh, you may want to have the vertex weights set to 1 to avoid the cloth physics impacting the shape of the cloth attached to the armature. First, for remove group, set a keyframe at beginning of sim with threshold 0, and keyframe falloff to linear.

[image: blender setting screenshot]

Duplicate this keyframe to the last keyframe where you want pinning in effect.
Then skip ahead 1 frame and set new keyframe with threshold 1 and a custom falloff curve with a control point mapping x=1 to y=0.

[image: blender setting screenshot]

Finally, if you don't want to release *all* pinned vertices, you can use a mask group to limit the Influence.